# Issue uploading Images

Tags: media, files

I have a Drupal 7 site that runs on Windows 7 and SQLServer.

Recently, when users try to upload pictures or files they get an error message:

> File could not be saved. An unknown error has occurred. The file was unable to be uploaded.

I have a development and a test site. The site was on Drupal 7.20, then upgraded to 7.23 and it worked for the development and the test sites. However, it did not work in production.

In production I upgraded to 7.23 and verified the elfinder is using library files 1.2.

I am not sure why this is happening: No code was changed before the Drupal core update, and the error is sporadic.

Comment: make sure sure file path settings at admin/config/media/file-system are appropriate as per the the server.Also check the file permissions to allow webserver to write images in the directory

Comment: The problem ended up being a server space issue. Increased space and the images were able to load.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola I will accept tomorrow I don't have high enough reputation yet to do it all same day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a server space issue. Increased space and the images were able to load.